# Xamrin iOS - AOT compilation fails from mac but builds fine from pc

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

I created [that simple xamarin forms app](https://github.com/FrancoisM/AotTests) (with just iOS). It does nothing but referencing that [signalr](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR/) nuget package.

When I build `Debug | iPhone` from Visual Studio on my pc (connected to my mac), it builds fine and especially does AOT compilation for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Sockets.Abstractions.dll` (as well as all other dlls).

However, when I build the same solution on Visual Studio for Mac, also on `Debug | iPhone`, I get the following error:

> Could not AOT the assembly
>   '/Users/francois/AotTests/AotTests/AotTests.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/Build/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Sockets.Abstractions.dll'
>   (MT3001) (AotTests.iOS)}

Comment: Try to change to `Link All` with Linker Behavior in iOS build  ,and uncheck `Enable incremental builds`

Comment: Same error with `Link All` and `Enable incremental builds` unchecked.

Comment: MT3001 errors can happen for many reasons (and only means the AOT compiler has not produce any output). As such stackoverflow is not the best place for them (most cases are unrelated). Please file an issue with Xamarin https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/new Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bonjour,

#### TL;DR

This has been fixed in https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/pull/3791 and we are trying to get it in our next stable release (aka 15.7).

You can try the fix with our continuous builds here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/wiki#continuous-builds.
In this case you want builds from master (hopefully soon from our 15.7 previous currently in alpha/beta).

---

#### What happened?

The NuGet package you added (`Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client`) was added via a new "package reference" mechanism and had dependencies (other packages) that had both `/lib` and `/ref` folders.

On the Mac, MSBuild's `ResolveAssemblyReferences` target resolved the reference assemblies (in `/ref`), passed them to `csc` to compile and because of that `mtouch` (our packaging tool) was also given those reference assemblies.
The problem is that we can't AOT them, they're only facades and are not made to be packaged.

We solved the issue in Xamarin.iOS (there might be a more general msbuild fix in the future) by stripping the right reference assemblies, given as output by the Nuget targets in `_ReferencesFromNuGetPackages`.

Comment: The issue is still there on the repro I shared in the question with Visual Studio 2017 for Mac Version 7.5 Preview (7.5 build 1062).

Comment: Can you share you VSMac version informations please? "Visual Studio" menu, "About Visual Studio" item, "Show Details" button.

Comment: Bug fixed with version 7.5 PReview (7.5 build 1244). What the eta for 7.5 in stable (as I need to build through vsts)?

Comment: well, it JUST got released. Tks msbuild!